# What categorical construction is this?

Tags: category-theory

I want to devise a construction on a concrete category where I select a preferred element of each object (which are sets) and then attach a real number to that element and then call this a new object in some other category.  I believe this is a functor from a category $C$ to something like $X \times R$, where $X \in Ob(C)$.  So, I take a concrete category then I map it to a category where every object is a set element paired with a real number.  This is like selecting the "best element" or some notion of "preferred element" from the set given a calculation I am able to do on the elements of the set $X$.  Is this a well known construction?  I am not sure what the morphisms are.  They may just be restrictions of the morphisms in $C$ down to the selected element.

Comment: As phrased, it is not clear enough what you mean. You really need to say what the morphisms are. In any case, this does not sound familiar.

Comment: I would split the problem in two. First define a sub-category of "nice" C call it C' and then define a full and faithful functor C' -> C. For the second part I suspect what you want lies in representation theory but I am not at all familiar with representation theory.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee Thanks for this suggestion!  I will consider it.

Comment: @IttayWeiss If I use the morphisms I mentioned, the restrictions, would this even be possible?  I am thinking of $C$ being concrete, so every morphism is really a function, and for each $f \in Mor(C)$ we take $F(f) = f'$ where $f'$ is the restriction of $f$, right down to the "preferred" element we selected.

Comment: It doesn’t look like you will have identities. Try to first write down a definition and check if you have a category. Once you have the construction written down, you can think of its properties.